# Shell script to count number of logins per day

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to Shell programming. I'm trying to write a shell script to count the number of logins per days of the week for users on some machine

Output should look like this:

```
123 Mon
231 Tue
555 Wed
21  Thu
44  Fri
123 Sat
10  Sun
```

I've tried to do it using commands last, uniq and sort like this

```
last -s -7days | awk '{print $1, $4,$5,$6}' | uniq -cd |sort -u
```

but I think I'm missing something because I'm somehow getting duplicated results. Also, I'm not sure how to get overall counts separated by days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `uniq` is it only collapses adjacent duplicates lines. In your case `-d` on uniq is hiding the lines that are breaking up the duplicate lines, I am guessing you have some lines similar to `reboot 4.4.5-1-ARCH Wed Mar` between login attempts for the day. You will also have problems with multiple users logging in breaking up the counts for other users.

Typically you `sort | uniq` to get a true list of uniq rows but if you remove the -d you end up with lines you do not want. These are best filtered out separately either before or after the `sort | uniq`.

Finally the last `sort -u` will delete data if two rows happen to match exactly, I do not think this is what you want. Instead it is better to sort on the date column (will cause a small issue on the month rollover) or by another column you care about with the `-k FILENUM` argument if you need to sort the counts at all.

Combine this together and you get:

```
last -s -7days | awk '/reboot/ {next}; /wtmp/ {next}; /^$/ {next}; {print $1, $4,$5,$6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 5
```

Note that `.../reboot/ {next};...` causes awk to ignore lines that match the pattern within the `/`s.